# jScrollpane mousewheel not working in all browsers

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am using jscrollpane. These are the file I am using in same sequence.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css">       
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">        
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
.
content
.
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.selectbox-0.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
```

This is how I am applying this plugin.

```
var api = $('.scroll-style').jScrollPane(
  {
       showArrows:false,
       maintainPosition: false,                 
   }
    ).data('jsp');
```

The problem is that scroll by mousewheel is not working properly in some browser(please refer the list).

how to adjust mousewheel speed?

Mousewheel working fine with -> chrome,IE9

Mousewheel not working at all with -> firefox 15, IE8

I highly required it in IE8 and firefox also.

Answer (score 1):

jquery.mousewheel.js - The jQuery mouseweel plugin. This is optional but recommended, include it to allow people to scroll your content using their mouse wheel.

[JQuery link here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not included the mousewheel js .
Please include the latest one from here https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/downloads

for mousewheel speed use **mouseWheelSpeed**

example jQuery('.scroll-style').jScrollPane({mouseWheelSpeed : 50});